# Why am I not getting events for a checkbox click in a treeview control?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

In my MFC dialog, i have a tree view control with checkboxes. Clicking the checkbox does not raise the NM_CLICK nor the TVN_SELCHANGED events, which I had hoped it would do.

How do I correctly determine when a checkbox is checked/unchecked in a tree view control?

Comment: Is it possible to provide some code? The declarations of the functions, the body of them, the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP (linkage with a function with the control) and the DoDataExchange (the linkage with a variable with the control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle mouse click normally and in the handler identify the current item and then use TreeView_GetCheckState to get its ***checked*** state.

Answer (score 1):

There is no notification of the click.

You'll find more information and a workaround here: http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B261289&x=19&y=11

Comment: That link is now broken...  8-(

Comment: You can find it here now: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/261289